# vimscript how do !xv @i successfully

Tags: bash, vim

In a register (`"i`) I have a string of one or more image file-paths relative to `pwd` that I wish to show in `xv` as a group. e.g. if `@i` contains say

```
' glosimgs/infcompcyme.jpg glosimgs/infcyme.jpg'
```

then I wish to achieve the same result as

```
!xv glosimgs/infcompcyme.jpg glosimgs/infcyme.jpg
```

But any way I try it using `eval` and/or elaborate quoting schemes one of two things happens. Either `@i` is passed unexpanded to bash because as soon as vim accesses `!` it passes the rest of the line to bash as-is, or vim expands `@i` but objects to `xv` as a non-existent variable.

How can I get vim to expand `@i` and only then pass the expanded command line to bash?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are typing the external command manually, and want to somehow fill the content of a register (@i), then you can type:

```
:!xv <c-r>i
```

`<c-r>` is `Ctrl-r`

Then you got what you want, if it is ok, press Enter.

`Ctrl-r` is very useful in Insert/Command mode. You may want to check `:h i_ctrl-r` for more valuable usage.

Comment: No, this is in a script, and executing '!xv <c-v><c-r>i" doesnt work either

Comment: @user985675 did mention `<c-v>` at all?

Comment: @user985675 If you want to use it in script, you can use `system() or execute` , just concatenate the register with dot (`.`)

Comment: Good tip, I've always assumed dot concatenation could only be done with literals, registers variables, but not with commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, but this does work
let @r='!xv '.@i
@r